# Do I need an UL approval if I build a machine and use it in my own company?

Tags: electric-machine

Do I need an UL approval (or any test lab) if I build a machine and use it in my own company?

Where can I find a legit documentation on this subject.

Comment: If you own a company, you better work with a lawyer.

Comment: It can depend on where you are located. It also can depend on what the item is and who may be operating it. At my workplace, we often get special inspection certificates from an AHJ for things like test equipment and process automation equipment, even though it would only be operated by skilled engineers and their subordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Check your contract with your insurance company. They might require all equipment used to have appropriate safety ratings in order to maintain your coverage.

Remember the "Underwriters" in Underwriters Laboratories means "insurance companies". UL is an organization set up by insurance companies to set standards for what kinds of equipment are safe enough to insure (i.e. to reduce the risk that insurance companies have to pay out on policies).

Comment: In addition, although the NEC does not mandate that equipment be UL listed, it does mandate some aspects of what you must comply with, which would be best (or can only be) accomplished by having an NRTL* listing. For example Article 409 will require that any "industrial control panel" carry what's called an "SCCR", Short Circuit Current Rating, which is equal or greater than the available fault current. It is difficult to get an SCCR without also getting listing by an NRTL. 

*NRTL = Nationally Recognized Testing Lab, of which UL is the best known example.

Answer (score 2):

More than likely if it is being powered directly from mains, it will need a UL (or equivalent, i.e. Intertek) approval. As The Photon indicated, this is ultimately an insurance issue; i.e. if your building burns down and the insurance company determines it was because of a non-Listed appliance, you will be in trouble.

With that said, if the device is powered by a Listed Class 2 (low voltage, low energy) supply many requirements are waived.

Comment: For clarity to the OP however, it should be noted that "Class 2" will mean it is limited to 100W total power. That's not going to be much of a "machine".

Comment: Very good point. Unlikely the Class 2 exception will help him.